# Read Cookies Using xcode in iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode

My application needs to be able to read cookies stored by a page loaded in the UIWebView. I need to be able to read the cookies using xcode so that I can store some values in application settings.
Does anyone know if its possible to read cookies using xcode?
Your help is much appreciated.
Stuck on this for ages.
Tony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [NSHTTPCookieStorage](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/) to read/modify cookies. `UIWebView` is using this storage.