# Is there a way to know if a mobile user previously visited a site via a QR code URL?

Tags: iphone, ios, qr-code

Client looking into using QR codes in print advertising that will reward the visitor with a discount. Simplest solution (to the best of my knowledge) is to make the QR code point to a unique URL (ex. using a GET parameter for a "coupon code") that is used to store a cookie and then check for that cookie upon checkout to apply the discount.

Now most of the QR apps I've been looking at have embedded browsers. If the user scans the code and completes the purchase right within the app, I believe the above solution would work.  But an ideal solution would allow the user to scan the code on the go and then visit the site up to X days later and still receive the discount. If a user returns to the site later they will probably use the mobile phone's standard browser app (i.e. Safari on iPhone) and not the app they originally used.

The [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532117/can-an-iphone-xcode-application-read-cookies-previously-stored-by-safari-mobile) says that "each SDK app is given its own WebKit cache and cookie stores, so while cookies will persist within the same app, they aren't accessible betweeen apps." So it seems impossible to me to use the above solution to enable a user to scan a QR code and visit the site later and guarantee that a discount would be applied. I cannot think of any other solutions, but before I conclude that it simply cannot be done I wanted to see if there are any other solutions I am simply not thinking of (short of having the user create an account and store it server-side)

P.S. Obviously there are other devices besides iPhones but if I can't even get it to work for iPhones that would be enough of a deal breaker. In fact the variety of possibilities regarding mobile devices and QR apps makes me think there's a very good chance that it really can't be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to setup a website that will can automatically give the discount to returning visitors across different web clients on iOS. You'll need the end user's help.

You could have the QR code link to a special landing page that tells the enduser to bookmark the page to get the discount at a later date. If QR app can save a bookmark, the end user will come back through the QR app. If the QR app can not save a bookmark, the end user will view the page in Safari and bookmark it there.

You could have the end user register for the discount, and then send a discount code by e-mail. Merely asking for an e-mail address should be sufficient. When he returns to get the discount he will use the e-mail with the discount code.

Comment: Thanks. These are the kinds of outside-the-box solutions I'm looking to explore.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is not to tie discounts to browsers, but to humans. Humans tend to have the same address, and fairly often the same credit card number. These are things that are much more valuable to check than cookies. If a given billing address or credit card # has been used for a discount before, then deny the discount on the second usage. This will solve the problem 90% of the time (and nothing will beat about 90% of the time).

Cookies are a fine first step (low-hanging fruit and all that), and are fine to check if they happen to be there, but keep in mind your actual goal. You want a single discount per paying customer, not a single discount per app/device/blah-blah-blah. All the latter are proxies for the former. Focus on things that identify actual paying customers.

Comment: Thanks. You're correct that I am not looking for "a single discount per app/device/blah-blah-blah." But I'm not looking for "a single discount per paying customer" or to _disable_ it on second usage. I'm looking for a way to _enable_ "a discount _only_ for users who scanned the QR code, and I'm just wondering if there's a cross-app way to do that.

Comment: I was focused on the denial case; but you're actually focused on the acceptance case. @Mr. Berna's ideas I believe are more constructive for what you're trying to achieve.