# Is there a trick to transfer metadata to mobile application before it's installed?

Tags: iphone, rest, qr-code

Here is a scenario I am struggling with:
We have a native application (both Android and iPhone) that is being downloaded after a QR code is scanned which sends the user to the App market.

I would like to transfer meta data about the specific QR code scanned prior to installation (assume there are several types of QR codes all leading to the same application).

How would I go about doing that?

I understand it isn't trivial as there's no application installed yet. What I am aiming at is having the QR code redirect the user to mydomain.com which will keep some data about the user and then redirect to App market. After the application is installed, I want to ask my server at mydomain.com about that user somehow.

Can I do something like that using cookies or anything similar? The process doesn't have to be reliable.

Thanks for your creativity,
Yuval Cohen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think this would be possible in iOS as even if you manage to store cookies in Safari, you wont be able to get the cookies from your app. Have a look at this..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/532533/919545

I am not sure about android though.