# Can i get Internet Cookies in Apple WatchKit?

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, watchkit

I'm making WatchKit app and really really need help...

My Project Flow likes this

1. There are company Lists in DB
2. Each Companies get there own URL
3. Each Web sites have same design, but save different Cookies

   ex) company A's URL --> save cookies like "company_name" , "A"

   company B's URL --> save cookies like "company_name" , "B"
4. After Save Cookies, WebSite redirects to AppStore
5. Download App and start App.
6. When App is Started, App Check Cookies
7. According to Cookies, App change App's Splash Label

For Step 6 and 7, I have to check cookies...

Is it Possible?? and then, How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no, it's not possible.

Each app manages it's own cookies and you can't access cookies set by other apps unless they indirectly allow it.

Mobile Safari, the default iOS browser doesn't provide any way of reading the cookies to other apps, nor should it, for privacy and security purposes.

See similar question here [Can an iPhone xcode application read cookies previously stored by Safari Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532117/can-an-iphone-xcode-application-read-cookies-previously-stored-by-safari-mobile)