# IOS 8 referral system

Tags: php, ios, iphone, swift, cookies

So I am working on a project currently in which referrals are a huge part. I was doing a little research and read that the app browser can not read safari's cookies. I also came across another answer [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532117/can-an-iphone-xcode-application-read-cookies-previously-stored-by-safari-mobile#answer-11432017) which would seem to work if the app already existed.

My plan is:

1) to have a link or QR code generated by a user (done)

2) When a user clicks the link take them to a page on my site and set a cookie (done)

3) Redirect user to the app store (easy)

4) When the user opens the app and signs up read the cookie which contains a special referral identifier generated by the server (This is where I'm lost)

I'm not sure if my plan is do-able but I have to make a system similar to it to figure out referrals.

-

How do I set cookies for an app that doesn't yet exist and once the app is installed read them?

Comment: If the app were already installed you could handle passing the referral info in -application:handleOpenURL: since it doesn't exist at that point though you can't open the app directly and get that data. Maybe it would be possible to ask the user to scan the QR code after installation.

Comment: What details are in the cookie? I would plan to do more than just check for referrer header (`$_SERVER[ 'HTTP_REFERER']`). The header may not be there or may not be what you expect.

Comment: Not that kind of referrer, i meant like a server generated referral id that would be part of the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 9, the new `SFSafariViewController` method of showing web pages is available. It lets you embed Safari directly into your app (rather than leaving the app), and it has access to a user's cookies and other personal information – I think this should do exactly what you want.

To get started, you need to `import SafariServices`, then show the new view controller like this:

```
let vc = SFSafariViewController(URL: someURL, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I wrote a [tutorial on SFSafariViewController](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/32) that you might find useful.