# can an iOS app read data written by my website?

Tags: ios, safari

I would like to redirect from my website to the AppStore to let users download my app. Afterwards, as soon as the user downloads and opens the app I need to identify it. So my question is if my website and app can read/write to the same storage/keychain/whatever. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Just a hunch: Maybe your website can ask the user to install a https client certificate for your server globally, which then might be able to be used by your app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5739402/5252706 This helps you?

Comment: no, because I need Safari to write data before the app is installed... Safari should write some data to the phone, redirect to the App Store, the app gets downloaded and reads the data written by Safari